# Getting menu heading title in template.php

Tags: routes

I am trying to edit a menu title (heading title) by customising the theme template file.

So far I have been able to customise both the UL and LI elements using THEME_menu_tree__MENU_NAME and THEME_menu_link__MENU_NAME hooks respectively. However, I cannot find a similar function to access the title of the menu.

If anyone has any ideas, I'd be happy to hear them.

Thanks.